# Jquery UI button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-button

Please take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/WAre9/4/

The problem is, after changing the text of link, `.button()` doesn't work properly.

Here is scrshot before:

[image]

And after mouse click:

[image]

As you see all paddings, font styles have gone. Any suggestion? How to fix this problem?

Comment: There are no styles in fiddle.

Comment: @loler updated. sorry for old link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [How do I replace jQueryUI button text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665937/how-do-i-replace-jqueryui-button-text)

> Maybe you could use the `label` option of the jQuery UI button now instead?
>
> ```
> $("#mybutton").button().toggle(function() {
>   $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Stop');
> }, function() {
>   $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Start');
> });
> ```
>
> [jsbin preview here](http://jsbin.com/iwina)

Comment: this worked for me, thx very much, but why 'option', 'label' not just 'label'??

Comment: if you go here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/ and look, it is because label is one of the 'options' of the button, you can look under methods too. hope this helps

Comment: One more thing, it's not related to this question but maybe you know. I'm using CSS reset technique, but jquery-ui widgets including button, are showing very huge, I mean font size. How can I scale size down?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `span` tag is removed after setting `element.text` see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WAre9/8/

or you can just change text of span element:

http://jsfiddle.net/WAre9/10/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bue3B/

use children('span').text...